# Forecasting in sas

Tags: sas, forecasting

I have a question about SAS. I have two time series S1 and S2. 
For S2 I have the predicted values for the next 3 years. I want to forecast S1 using S2 and its foretasted values. Usually, if I don't have the foretasted values for any of the series I would use something like this.
(Forecasting sales using price as an input series with ARIMA(1,1,1)

```
proc arima data=mydata;
identify var=price(1);
estimate p=2;
identify var=sales(1) crosscorr=price(1);
estimate p=1 q=1 input=price;
forecast lead=12 interval=month id=date out=results;
run;e here
```

Comment: It's not clear (to me) what your question is.

Answer (score 0):

`PROC ARIMA` is interactive in that it executes each statement individually. As such, it also can use information derived from the previous statement. To use forecasts of your input variable, you will need to add another `forecast` statement below it. This will internally generate a forecast for your input variable, and allow you to use that forecast as an input into your primary variable of interest.

```
proc arima data=mydata;
    identify var=price(1) noprint;
        estimate p=2 noprint;
        forecast lead=12 noprint;
    identify var=sales(1) crosscorr=(price(1) );
        estimate p=1 q=1 input=price;
        forecast lead=12 interval=month id=date out=results;
run;
```

If you already have the forecasts and they are in a separate dataset, simply merge the two datasets together:

```
data want;
    merge have_s1
          have_s2;
    by date;
run;

    dataset: want
date        s1    s2
1/1/15      10    96
2/1/15      15    80
3/1/15      9     120
....        ...   ...
12/1/15     4     160
1/1/16      .     133
2/1/16      .     121
3/1/16      .     100
```

Then you can run `PROC ARIMA` on the dataset, and it will fill in the missing values of `s1` as far as you have values for `s2`.

```
proc arima data=want;
    identify var=s1(1) crosscorr=(s2(1) );
    estimate p=1 q=2;
    forecast lead=12 interval=month id=date out=results;
run;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Stu for taking the time to answer my question. That's the right answer and that's what I did.